# How do I handle a "fixed content" model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In some of my forms I have to provide a dropdown where users can select some districts. The thing is, there will always be a fixed number of districts ( 31 in this case ). Should I create a model named `District` having only a string field,populate it with the data and be done with it?

It's content will not modify over time. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [jnunemakers scam-gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/scam). It mimics the AR for you and lets you define the models in your Rails app without a backing database/table.

> I use this whenever I want something to do psuedo belongs to/has many relationships, but do not want to back a model with a database as the data does not change often, if ever.

Answer (score 1):

Making a table-backed model is the simplest way. Otherwise you're going to end up implementing half of an AR model anyway, because you'll want to use collection_select at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on how you want to store the districts and whether you want to do any querying etc.

For example, you could just have the list of districts as a constant, then store them as a string in your models (not very elegant), or as you say you could create a model and use active record associations - this would allow you to easily query on districts etc.